# Can't figure out this in Holub's pattern book

Tags: design-patterns, errata

I started reading Holub's pattern book and not sure if this is a mistake (pg 59-61).

He has in listing 2-3

```
public interface Employee
{ void youAreFired();
}

public static class EmployeeFactory
{  private Factory() {}

 public static Employee create()
 {   return new Peon();
 }
 }

/* package*/ class Peon implements Employee
{   public void youAreFired()
    {  //lots of code
    }
 }
```

He is using `Employee.Factory.create()`. Factory is not a inner class of Employee, so how is using that?

Then two pages down he says `Employee.Factory` is a singleton. How? I think its a typo, `Factory` or `Employee.Factory` should actually be `EmployeeFactory`. I hope I am not missing something major in Java programming!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeb there is single typo only:
Proposed fix:
the line `public static class EmployeeFactory` => `public static class Factory`

revise what you wrote after considering above fix shall result in clearing the vision.

Answer (score 1):

I bet he just meant "EmployeeFactory" in both those cases.  It looks like just a typo.